# c# get reference to newed-up class and feed it into it's own method inline

Tags: c#, chaining

```
public class Kitten
{     
    public  string Ears = "NotSet";
    public  string Fur = "NotSet";      
}

public class Cage
{ 

    Kitten _kitten;

    public Cage(Kitten Akitten)
    {

    }

    public Kitten Kitten
    {
        get
        {
            return _kitten;
        }

        set
        {
            _kitten = value;
        }
    }

    public string EchoKittenProperty(string PropName)
    {  
        return PropName;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to gain access to the newed class and spit it into the method inline?

This is easy:

```
var cg = new Cage( new Kitten(){  Ears = "Pointy", Fur = "Fluffy" });
var value = cg.EchoKittenProperty(cg.Kitten.Fur);
//value = "Fluffy"
```

But how do I do this:

```
var value = new Cage( new Kitten(){  Ears = "Pointy", Fur = "Fluffy" }).EchoKittenProperty(this.Kitten.Fur);
//value = "Fluffy"
```

This is a test class:

```
public static class Test
{        
   public static void Test1()
   {             
        var cg = new Cage( new Kitten(){  Ears = "Pointy", Fur = "Fluffy" });
        var value = cg.EchoKittenProperty(cg.Kitten.Fur); 
        //value = "Fluffy"
   } 

   public static void Test2()
   {  
     //"this" is illegal here, but I want to get "this" to refer to the new Cage class           
     var value = new Cage( new Kitten(){  Ears = "Pointy", Fur = "Fluffy"}).EchoKittenProperty(this.Kitten.Fur);
     //value = "Fluffy"
   } 
}
```

Is there any way to reference the newed object in the EchoKittenProperty method inline without putting it into a variable and referencing it after?

**I think something like this allows you to chain the methods and get access to the instance**:

```
public class Cage
{ 
    public Cage EchoKittenProperty(Func<Cage, Cage> projection)
    {
        return projection(this);
    }

    Kitten _kitten;

    public Cage(Kitten Akitten)
    {

    }

    public Kitten Kitten
    {
        get
        {
            return _kitten;
        }

        set
        {
            _kitten = value;
        }
    }



    public Tuple<string,string> GetKittenInfo()
    { 

        return new Tuple<string, string>(this.Kitten.Fur, this.Kitten.Ears);

    }
}
```

**Now you can chain without holding the kitten as a variable outside the class.**

```
var KittenInfo = new Cage(new Kitten(){ })
        .EchoKittenProperty(i => 
        {                
            i.Kitten.Ears = "Pointy";                
            return i;
        }
        )
        .EchoKittenProperty( i =>
        {
            i.Kitten.Fur = "Fluffy";
           return i;
        }
        )
        .GetKittenInfo();
```

Here is what you can do with dbextensions and dapper:

```
List<Customer> Customers = SQLHelper.Select<Customer>(new Customer())
.Chain(x=> x.AddWhere(new MysqlWhere(nameof(x.Item.CustomerID), 25, MysqlWhere.OperatorEnum.Equals)))
.SelectAllWhere();
```

We wanted access to the generic with the chain so we can get strongly typed properties.

Was using EF with Mysql for awhile but overall it doesn't work well. Though the selects in EF are much easier with Fluent methods.

Comment: What is `printout`? That's not normal C#...?

Comment: Sorry for the pseudo code, let me know if that helps clarify. I'm trying to figure out how to reference parts of the newed up class later in a chained method.

Comment: No, you'd have to capture the instance in order to refer to one of it's properties.

Comment: Hmmm Rufus is there any way you can accomplish this using generics, or lambda expressions or a combination?

Comment: The problem is, I'm trying to chain it, so I would like to use that concept in more than 1 chain. Ideally, new Cage( new Kitten(){  Ears = "Pointy", Fur = "Fluffy"}).EchoKittenProperty(this.Kitten.Fur).EchoKittenProperty(this.Kitten.Ears), not necesarily returning a string but building up an internal list. I'll have to test out maybe chaining static methods? Not sure.

Comment: Method chaining works because because a method returns a value that you can call another method on (i.e. `new Cage(...).EchoKittenProperty(...).Substring(...).Length`). But here you're trying to pass an instance property to a method without having captured the instance. I don't know of any way you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified `Cage` a little, but here's what you need to do:

```
public class Cage
{
    public Cage(Kitten kitten)
    {
        this.Kitten = kitten;
    }

    public Kitten Kitten { get; set; }

    public string EchoKittenProperty(Func<Kitten, string> projection)
    {
        return projection(this.Kitten);
    }
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
string value = new Cage(new Kitten { Ears = "Pointy", Fur = "Fluffy" })
    .EchoKittenProperty(x => x.Fur);
```

And now `value` is equal to `"Fluffy"`

However, that means you've just lost the reference to `Cage` itself, and that makes this seem a little pointless. I'd be interested to know what you're trying to do with this method so that I can suggest a more robust answer.

Comment: I'm building up SQL statements with https://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions nothing too exciting.

Comment: @Watson - Then you probably want fluent methods. It would be great to understand more as I think what you've asked doesn't feel right for building up SQL statements.

Comment: I think you're onto something.